# UIButton animation with auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, uianimation

I want my `UIButton` to make a `UIAnimation` where it gets resized and repositioned when clicked. But it seems this can't be done when the `UIButton` is using `auto layout`.

This is the code I want to perform:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:.15];
     [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 20, 20)];
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But as long as this `button` uses `auto layout` and `contraints` the animation won't be performed. What is the solution here? Work around?

Comment: You need to modify the constraints, not the frame.

Comment: @Paulw11 is it posible to ignore the constrains some how? Or remove them?

Comment: Only by not using autolayout. Animating the constraints is quite straightforward. See the duplicate

Comment: You can create @IBOutlets for the constraints that you want to change just like you do for the button itself